# Duplicate Class error in my kotlin file, How can i fix this?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to create a multi activity app with firebase auth and database, but during build, i kept encountering Duplicate Class error

This is my error log

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
```

this is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.gpsmeasurementapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gpsmeasurementapp"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

}
```

I have tried removing duplicate dependencies but the problem persists
I have added `android.enableJetifier=true` as i saw it in another question but the same errors are shown

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency {
                if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
                    useVersion("1.6.10")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this fixed the issue